# MStest > OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, mstest

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe
>   file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the
>   PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

I have some automation in Visual Studio and I want to integrate it with Jenkins by MStest, I tested it by console but it shows me that error, already tried several things but I have not yet been able to, I don't know if I should create a service I have seen it in some comments but not I know how to do it, if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it

Visual Studio 2019, Csharp, MSTest

Comment: Already tried several things? What have you tried?